# Can't get auth token stored in flutter secure storage to headers

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I am making flutter app using API and I have a problem. When I want to get auth token to make request, flutter says that "Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type '_Future'". How can I make a request with auth token without that error?

My login function, where I write the token:

```
loginUser() async {
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/account/login");
    await http
        .post(uri,
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            body: jsonEncode({
              "username": emailController.text,
              "password": passwordController.text
            }))
        .then((response) async {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = json.decode(response.body);
        await storage.write(key: "token", value: data["token"]);
        print(data["token"]);
      } else {
        print(json.decode(response.body));
      }
    });
  }
```

My getdata function, where i use the token:

```
getdata() async {
    final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/account/countries");
    await http.get(uri, headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": await storage.read(key: "token")
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
String token = await storage.read(key: 'token');

 //make sure if there is no Bearer just token in that case just pass the token
     
    var headers = {
       'accept': 'application/json',
       'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}',
    };
    
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/account/countries");
    
    Response response = await http.get(
        uri, 
        headers: headers
    );
    
    print (response);
```

Comment: The result of `storage.read` might be a null String, so it would be necessary to insert a check for that as well

Comment: the check should be when the app starts if the token is null or expired redirect the user to the login screen once the user request this endpoint it should mean the token is valid, and I would recommend using dio with interceptors to handle the 401 status code also here the link  https://pub.dev/packages/dio#interceptors